# How to check health of docker image running sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, sidekiq

I'm using kubernetes on my cluster with several rails / node docker images. Most of them have :3000/healtz health check that simply returns status 200 with OK in body.

Now I'm trying to discover the best way how this health check can be performed on docker image running sidekiq. How I can verify that the worker is running?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring

Answer (score 4):

If your image is unix like, you can check if the proccess is running with

```
$ ps aux | grep '[s]idekiq'
```

But this don't guarantee that everything is working inside sidekiq and redis.

A better approach is described/developed in this sidekiq plugin https://github.com/arturictus/sidekiq_alive

I'm facing problems with `livenessProbe` for k8s and trying to solve without using this lib but not successful yet.

Comment: Surely a healthcheck (liveness probe) that just checks whether the process appears in `ps` output would be redundant, since kubelet will restart the container anyway if the process fails? I'm assuming that sidekiq is running in its own container (and that `restartPolicy` isn't set to Never). https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#when-should-you-use-a-liveness-probe

Comment: I ended up using this `ps` trick in the readiness probes, and delayed it by 30 seconds to make sure sidekiq does not crash during boot (e.g. because of missing configuration).

Answer (score 4):

You have different approaches depending mostly on how you deployed Sidekiq inside the Kubernetes pod.

Here some of them.

**SIDEKIQMON**

Since Sidekiq v6 we have [sidekiqmon](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#sidekiqmon)

You can try with something like:

```sh
bundle exec sidekiqmon processes | grep $(hostname)
```

To make it work you must be able to grep the correct running process related to current pod/container.

**PS AUX** (I used in the past)

Something like this could work:

```sh
ps aux | grep '[s]idekiq 6'
```

Note the 6 (sidekiq version) at the end to differentiate from the other process that you could have.
Anyway here the idea is to just check your processes with `ps aux` and try to "grep" the sidekiq one you need to monitor.

**SIDEKIQ_ALIVE**

Another approach is to use [sidekiq_alive](https://github.com/arturictus/sidekiq_alive)
But it requires more effort to be configured and managed and I never really tried it. This is the only one that really check the full functionality with also the Redis status.

**SYSTEMCTL**

If you deployed sidekiq using `systemd` you can just do:

```sh
systemctl status sidekiq | grep '[r]unning'"
```

**So at the end my YAML manifest for Sidekiq deployment looks like this:**

```yaml
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c", "bundle exec sidekiqmon processes | grep $(hostname)"]
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 30
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 30
```

Note that only the sidekiq_alive approach is going to perform a full end to end test, checking also the redis status. Maybe this is too much, you could have other monitoring system for Redis so maybe here, with the kubernetes LivenessProbes, you don't need to check the whole flow but just check if the sidekiq process is still alive or crashed due to a memory leak. This is up to you, based on your needs.

*"Why you need this kind of LivenessProbes?"*

Because if you are launching Sidekiq via systemd or similar, you will have the main process (PID 1) as `/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/systemctl start sidekiq` and the related process launched with ExecStart as `sidekiq 6.1.3 your_app_name [0 of 5 busy]`. If you have a memory leak, the last one will crash and not the PID 1.
For this reason you need a sort of livenessProbes for Sidekiq.

Instead if you are not using systemd and your PID 1 is `sidekiq 6.1.3 your_app_name [0 of 5 busy]` because you are launching it with `bundle exec sidekiq` you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq 6.0 ships with a new `sidekiqmon`, which you could use to validate that a process is running on your current machine with redis:

```sh
REDIS_URL=redis://redis.example.com:6380/5 sidekiqmon | grep $$(hostname)
```

Documentation: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#sidekiqmon